# error mongoose (node:3760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: cargoSchema is not a constructor

Tags: mongoose

Estoy teniendo este error con un esquema

```js
//esquema
const Mongoose       = require('mongoose');
const mongooseDelete = require('mongoose-delete');
const Schema         = Mongoose.Schema;
const conceptoSchema = require('./conceptoSchema');


var cargoSchema = new Schema({
    fecha_alta: {default: Date.now, type: Date},
    nombre: String,
    cargo: Number,
    nomenclatura: String,
    indice: Number,
    categoria_codigo: String,
    conceptos_template: []
});

cargoSchema.plugin(mongooseDelete, { overrideMethods: true, deletedAt: true });

Mongoose.model('cargos', cargoSchema, 'cargos');

module.exports = cargoSchema;

//fragmento de la app

        var TCargos = new cargoSchema( {
                fecha_alta: Date,
                nombre: aCargos[ i ][ 1 ],
                cargo: parseInt( aCargos[ i ][ 2 ] ),
                nomenclatura: aCargos[ i ][ 4 ],    
                indice: parseFloat( aCargos[ i ][ 5 ] ),
                categoria_codigo: aCargos[ i ][ 3 ],
                conceptos_template: []
            } );
```

Comment: tu codigo debe ser algo como https://pastebin.com/nV1ZsY5g

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algunos errores en la forma en que quieres usar tu modelo y en la forma incluso que lo implementas.

**PROBLEMA**

Tratas de usar un modelo pero estás llamando erróneamente al `Schema`. Además la cláusula que usas para crear el modelo no es correcta, ya que pasas 2 veces el nombre que identificará al modelo.

Otra cosa, no uses `var` para definir el `Schema`, ya que el esquema no va a variar, es un molde para crear modelos a partir de este.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para utilizar un modelo de `mongoose`, primero debemos instanciar o crear un `Schema`, dicho esquema servirá de molde para el modelo. Una vez creado el esquema, podemos crear el modelo usando el método `mongoose.model()`, al cual le pasamos como argumentos: el nombre que deseamos darle al modelo y el `Schema` que usará dicho modelo. Por último, es el modelo lo que vamos a exportar en `module.exports`, no el `Schema`.

Suponiendo que tu modelo se llama `Cargos`, vamos primero a crear un `Schema` llamado `cargoSchema`.

Crearemos un archivo llamado `cargos.model.js` y en dicho archivo escribiremos lo siguiente:

(Usando ES5:)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongooseDelete = require('mongoose-delete');

// podemos usar 'const' en vez de 'var', el schema no varía, el documento creado
// a partir del schema es lo que varía.
const cargoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fecha_alta: {default: Date.now, type: Date},
    nombre: String,
    cargo: Number,
    nomenclatura: String,
    indice: Number,
    categoria_codigo: String,
    conceptos_template: []
});

//adherimos nuestro plugin
cargoSchema.plugin(mongooseDelete, { overrideMethods: true, deletedAt: true });

//ahora exportamos el 'Modelo', pero debemos darle un nombre
//usaremos 'Cargos' como el nombre del módulo a exportar
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cargos', cargoSchema);
```

Ya tenemos creado nuestro modelo, ahora vamos a usarlo. Suponiendo que lo usaremos directamente en `app.js`, esto debe incluirse en nuestro archivo `app.js`:

(Usando ES5):

```
... //aqui van otros 'require' según sea el caso
const Cargos = require('./ruta/hacia/cargos.model.js');
...
// ahora podemos instanciar un documento usando 'Cargos' como constructor
// tal vez sea preferible usar 'let' a cambio de 'var'
let cargos = new Cargos({
    fecha_alta: Date,
    nombre: aCargos[ i ][ 1 ],
    cargo: parseInt( aCargos[ i ][ 2 ] ),
    nomenclatura: aCargos[ i ][ 4 ],    
    indice: parseFloat( aCargos[ i ][ 5 ] ),
    categoria_codigo: aCargos[ i ][ 3 ],
    conceptos_template: []
});
```

De esta forma usamos correctamente el modelo `Cargos` creado a partir de `cargoSchema`.

Observando bien el código, `Cargos` es el constructor, cada documento nuevo del tipo `Cargos` que queramos crear debemos hacer usando `new Cargos({...})`.

Espero que esto ayude a resolver tu problema.